# Computing norm of a linear application in $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I am trying to solve this problem but I am stuck, I think because I can't understand the general mechanism or the sense of what I am doing.

I have to compute the norm in $C([0,1])$ (the set of all continuous functions in the real interval $[0,1]$) endowed with $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ of $T(f)=\int_{0}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$ where $g \in C([0,1])$ is a given mapping with $g(\frac{1}{2})=0$ and $g(x)\neq 0$ for any other $x \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

In class, we defined the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm of a continuous function f as $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$.

This is what I have done: $$\|Tf(x)\|_{\infty}=\sup_{[0,1]}\left|\int_{0}^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right| \leq \int_{0}^1 \sup_{[0,1]} |f(x)||g(x)|dx \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \|g\|_{\infty} $$

But now I am stuck. I can't understand how to actually compute this norm, I believe making the derivative of the integral to maximize the function could play a role, but I can't  understand why.

I have other similar exercises and I am having some troubles with them as well, so probably I am missing something important.

Thank you

Comment: What's $X$? $X=C[0,1]$?

Comment: Neigher $T$ nor $T(f)$ is in $C([0,1])$ so your question doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to compute the operator norm of $T$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. $X=C([0,1]) $ and the exercise just says to compute the norm of the application $T$.

Comment: OK well it cannot be the supremum norm of $T$, since that doesn't make sense. It is likely that you are being asked to compute the operator norm of $T$, which is defined as $\lVert T\rVert = \sup\frac{\lvert T(f)\rvert}{\lVert f\rVert}$

Comment: It seems $T:C([0,1]) \to \mathbb C$. I.e., $T$ is a linear functional on $C([0,1])$, not a linear map from $C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is I am using the wrong definition of $||T(f)||_{\infty}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that
$$
|T(f)| \leq \|f\|_\infty \int_0^1 |g|,
$$
hence $\|T\| \leq \int_0^1 |f|$.

Under the given assumptions on $g$, you have that $g$ has a fixed sign on $[0,1/2)$ and $(1/2, 1]$.
Hence, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the function
$$
f_n(x) := \text{sign}(g(x)) h_n(x),
\qquad h_n(x) := \min\{1, n |x-1/2|\} 
$$
is continuous, $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$, and, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$
|T(f_n)| = \int_0^1 |g| h_n \to \int_0^1 |g|.
$$
Thus we can conclude that $\|T\| = \int_0^1 |g|$.